# HTAccess Allowing Login By Using Name As Password

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have an issue where my server is accepting a faulty password for my site.

For example, my domain name might be "johndoe.com" and the scenario is

- ht login name: **johndoe**
- ht password: **johndoe123**

Which works fine to log me in, however there is a small issue. For some reason I can also use my login name as the password and it will let me in! I tried using a random password but that didn't work (expected behavior).

I looked at my .htpasswd and it looks like this:

```
johndoe:rpFVb9n8R.p9c
```

So how is it that my password and my login name are both working as a *correct* password? This one is beyond me :/

Comment: Please post the relevant sections of your Apache config and any .htaccess files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be using crypt for your password, based on the hash. Old versions of crypt effectively only use the first 8 characters of your password, so if the shared-prefix of your username and password is longer than that, that would cause the symptoms you're seeing.

Don't use crypt, use SHA instead; run `htpasswd` with the `-s` flag, e.g.

```
$ htpasswd -bs /path/to/htpasswd johndoe johndoe123
```

Comment: I've been looking for an answer for this for some time now. You are a gentleman and a scholar.